# SwiftUI ForEach Nested Struct - Compiler Timing Out and Failing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am having a problem with a nested struct that is populated from a JSON endpoint. I have worked out the decoding and got that all working. I am now having a problem using a nested ForEach function in a SwiftUI View.

Here is the JSON data that comes from my endpoint

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Authorized",
    "personData": {
        "PersonID": 31457,
        "Name": "John Johnson Doe",
        "Sex": "m",
        "Living": 0,
        "BirthDate": "28 Dec 1965",
        "DeathDate": "22 Dec 1995",
        "BirthPlace": "Detroit, Michigan, USA",
        "DeathPlace": "Avon, Oakland, Michigan",
        "FatherName": "Kenneth William Doe",
        "MotherName": "Dorothy Anna Hunter",
        "Siblings": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "SiblingName": "Katrina Ann Doe"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "SiblingName": "Iris Marie Doe"
            }
        ],
        "Marriages": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "FamilyID": 10866,
                "SpouseID": 31487,
                "SpouseName": "Louise Bernadette Timbers",
                "MarriageDate": "26 Sep 1985",
                "MarriagePlace": "Clark County, Indiana, USA",
                "DivorceDate": "27 Oct 1999",
                "Children": [
                    {
                        "id": 100,
                        "ChildName": "Timoth Kenneth Doe"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "FamilyID": 10867,
                "SpouseID": 31461,
                "SpouseName": "Wendy Mae Jackson",
                "MarriageDate": "1 May 2001",
                "MarriagePlace": "Detroit, Wayne, Michigan, USA",
                "DivorceDate": "-",
                "Children": [
                    {
                        "id": 100,
                        "ChildName": "Patricia Ann Doe"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 101,
                        "ChildName": "Allen Kenneth Doe"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 102,
                        "ChildName": "Stephen Patrick Doe"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have some Observables along with a function which requests the data from the API and decodes it into personData

```
class NetworkRouter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPersonLoaded: Bool = false
    @Published var personData: PersonData?

func getPersonData(personID: Int) {
        let data = KeychainHelper.standard.read(service: "token", account: "blahblah")!
        let token = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        Webservice().getPersonData(token: token, personID: personID) { (result) in
            switch result {
                case .success(let personData):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.personData = personData
                        self.isPersonLoaded = true
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the struct definitions to help decode the JSON

```
struct PersonResponse: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let message: String
    let personData: PersonData
}

struct PersonData: Codable {
    let personID: Int
    let name, sex: String
    let living: Int
    let birthDate, deathDate, birthPlace, deathPlace: String
    let fatherName, motherName: String
    let siblings: [Sibling]
    let marriages: [Marriage]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case personID = "PersonID"
        case name = "Name"
        case sex = "Sex"
        case living = "Living"
        case birthDate = "BirthDate"
        case deathDate = "DeathDate"
        case birthPlace = "BirthPlace"
        case deathPlace = "DeathPlace"
        case fatherName = "FatherName"
        case motherName = "MotherName"
        case siblings = "Siblings"
        case marriages = "Marriages"
    }
}

struct Marriage: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id, familyID, spouseID: Int
    let spouseName, marriageDate, marriagePlace, divorceDate: String
    let children: [Child]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case familyID = "FamilyID"
        case spouseID = "SpouseID"
        case spouseName = "SpouseName"
        case marriageDate = "MarriageDate"
        case marriagePlace = "MarriagePlace"
        case divorceDate = "DivorceDate"
        case children = "Children"
    }
}

struct Child: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let childName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case childName = "ChildName"
    }
}

struct Sibling: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let siblingName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case siblingName = "SiblingName"
    }
}
```

I have attempted the following methods for looping through each marriage and displaying the children

```
struct PersonProfileMarriageView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var networkRouter: NetworkRouter
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(networkRouter.personData!.marriages) { thisMarriage in
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                    Text("SPOUSE")
                    Text("\(thisMarriage.spouseName)")
                }
                if thisMarriage.marriageDate != "-" {
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                        Text("MARRIAGE DATE")
                        Text("\(thisMarriage.marriageDate)")
                    }
                }
                if thisMarriage.children.count > 0 {
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing:0) {
                        Text("CHILDREN")
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(thisMarriage.children) { thisChild in
                                Text("\(thisChild.childName)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried this type of ForEeach

```
ForEach(networkRouter.personData!.marriages, id: \.id) { thisMarriage in
    ForEach(thisMarriage.children) { children in

    }
}
```

And this method

```
ForEach(networkRouter.personData!.marriages, id: \.id) { thisMarriage in
    ForEach(thisMarriage.children, id: \.id) { thisChild in

    }
}
```

All of those produce the dreaded "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

I really have no idea how to "break this up"

The only way I managed to get this to work was by using a List in this manner which seems very hacky.

```
List(networkRouter.personData!.marriages) { thisMarriage in
    ForEach(thisMarriage.children, id: \.id) { thisChild in

    }
}
```

I could very much use some help on this one. I been at it for days with no success. I have tried to make things Identifiable. Made sure the Marriage IDs and Child IDs were unique.
I really dislike using the List as it causes complications with other things I'm trying to do.

Hopefully I have provided all the code necessary to assist. Please let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: This is common with Swiftui, when the content of the `body` is too intricate, even if the logic works. You just need one comma out of place to get the compiler suffering. Start by moving the `HStack`s out of the `body`, for example each one to a `private func something(...) -> some View`. You might get some chance in compiling or finding the mistake. The key is to break that body down into smaller pieces.

Comment: Person Data should conform to Identifiable or declare he id explicitly. You can also try commenting out chunks there is likely a typo or something that can be more specific.

Comment: I chunked it down. Posted a working result. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback I was able to "break down" the view a bit more into sub views. Thanks for the tips. The following is working.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PersonProfileMarriageView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var networkRouter: NetworkRouter
    var body: some View {
        if networkRouter.personData!.marriages.count > 0 {
            VStack {
                ForEach(networkRouter.personData!.marriages) { thisMarriage in
                    PersonProfileMarriageSpouseNameView(marriage: thisMarriage)
                    PersonProfileMarriageDateView(marriage: thisMarriage)
                    if thisMarriage.children.count > 0 {
                        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing:0) {
                            Text("CHILDREN")
                            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                 ForEach(thisMarriage.children) { children in
                                     PersonProfileChildView(child: children)
                                 }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```